# Как сортировать по пункту char, но чтобы другие char в структуре подвязывались под сортировочный? с++

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка, char

У меня есть 4 массива чар в журнале, мне нужно отсортировать по имени. Сортировку по имени я написал, но type, oblast, kolvo остаются на местах. Как сделать так чтобы они тоже подвязывались под мой name чар?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

const int maxlen = 255;
#pragma pack(push, 1) //директиви компілятору для вирівнювання полів структур
struct sworker {
    char type[maxlen];
    char name[maxlen];
    char oblast[maxlen];
    char kolvo[maxlen];
};
#pragma pack(pop) //директиви компілятору для вирівнювання полів структур

sworker arr[maxlen];
int worker_index = 0;

int menu();//прототипи функцій
void readFromFile(const char* fileName);
void saveToFile(const char* fileName);
void addNew();
void del();
void sort();

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    while (1) {  //створення нескінченного циклу з меню вибору, виклик відповідних функцій 
        switch (menu()) {
        case 1:
            readFromFile("file.dat");
            break;
        case 2:
            saveToFile("file.dat");
            break;
        case 3:
            addNew();
            break;
        case 4:
            del();
            break;
        case 5:
            sort();
            break;
        case 6:
            return 0;
        default:
            cout << "Nevirniy vibir" << endl;
        }
    }
}
int menu()//функція показує пункти меню вибору
{
    cout << "\n";
    int ans;
    cout << "choose\n";
    cout << "1-zchituvannya z fayla\n";
    cout << "2-zapis v fayl\n";
    cout << "3-dodavannya zapisu\n";
    cout << "4-vidalennya zapisu\n";
    cout << "5-sortyrovaty za nazvoyu\n";
    cout << "6-exit\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Vash vibir  ";
    cin >> ans;
    return ans;
}
void saveToFile(const char* fileName) //функція, що записує дані у бінарний файл
{
    ofstream f;
    f.open(fileName, ios::binary);
    f.write((char*)arr, sizeof(sworker) * worker_index);
    f.close();
    cout << "vvedeni dani zberezheni do failu\n";
}
void readFromFile(const char* fileName) //функція, що зчитує дані з бінарного файлу
{
    ifstream f;
    f.open(fileName, ios::binary);
    if (!f) {
        cout << "Failu ne isnue";
    }
    else {
        sworker worker;
        worker_index = 0;
        while (1) {
            f.read((char*)&worker, sizeof(worker));
            if (f.eof())
                break;
            arr[worker_index] = worker;
            worker_index++;
        }
        f.close();
        cout << "Dani zchitano z failu\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < worker_index; i++) {
            cout << i + 1 << "\t" << arr[i].type << "\t" << arr[i].name << "\t" << arr[i].oblast << "\t" << arr[i].kolvo << endl;
        }
    }
}
void addNew()//функція, що додає(створює) новий запис
{
    cout << "Dodavannya novogo zapisu\n\n";
    cout << "Vvedit type ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(arr[worker_index].type, maxlen);
    cout << "Vvedit name ";
    cin.getline(arr[worker_index].name, maxlen);
    cout << "Vvedit oblast ";
    cin.getline(arr[worker_index].oblast, maxlen);
    cout << "Vvedit kolvo  ";
    cin >> arr[worker_index].kolvo;
    worker_index++;
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < worker_index; i++) {
        cout << i + 1 << "\t" << arr[i].type << "\t" << arr[i].name << "\t" << arr[i].oblast << "\t" << arr[i].kolvo << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

void del()//функція, що видаляє запис 
{
    int d;
    cout << "Oberit nomer zapisu yakiy treba vidaliti ";
    cin >> d;
    for (int i = d - 1; i < worker_index; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    }
    worker_index--;

    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < worker_index; i++) {
        cout << i + 1 << "\t" << arr[i].type << "\t" << arr[i].name << "\t" << arr[i].oblast << "\t" << arr[i].kolvo << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

void sort()
{
    char cur[30];
    for (int i = 0; i < worker_index - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < worker_index; j++)
            if (strcmp(arr[i].name, arr[j].name) > 0)
            {
                strcpy_s(cur, arr[i].name);
                strcpy_s(arr[i].name, arr[j].name);
                strcpy_s(arr[j].name, cur);
            }

    for (int i = 0; i < worker_index; i++) {
        cout << i + 1 << "\t" << arr[i].type << "\t" << arr[i].name << "\t" << arr[i].oblast << "\t" << arr[i].kolvo << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Просто обменивайте не один член `name`, а весь `arr[j]`. Но чтобы не дергаться с большими пересылками памяти, проще собрать массив указателей, и сортировать его.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так:

```
void sort()
{
    sworker tmp;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < worker_index - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < worker_index; j++)
            if (strcmp(arr[i].name, arr[j].name) > 0)
            {
                tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
            }

        for (int i = 0; i < worker_index; i++) {
            cout << i + 1 << "\t" << arr[i].type << "\t" << arr[i].name << "\t" << arr[i].oblast << "\t" << arr[i].kolvo << endl;
        }
        cout << "\n";
}
```